# Where is the gwt icon to compile the project in GWT 2.7?

Tags: java, gwt

I used GWT version 2.6, after compiling, an icon is displayed in the browser (bottom right corner) where you could re-compile the project.

[image]

To switch to GWT 2.7, this icon does not appear

How I can enable this icon in GWT 2.7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is no longer needed in GWT 2.7 SuperDev mode. With GWT 2.7 there is the incremental compilation, which speeds up your development, because not the whole project, but only the changed parts get recompiled. When reloading the page it should automatically be recompiled.

Comment: I checked what you say in my test project, effectively to reload the page the changes are automatically reflected. Thank you